# Python API – Access Grease Pencil stroke point weights

Tags: python, scripting, armature, weight-painting, grease-pencil

I need to read Grease Pencil bone weights from the Python API so I can add that data to an export script I'm using. I can't find where the per-point weight groups are stored. So far, I'm able to access the point positions, pressure, strength, etc through [GPencilStrokePoint](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.GPencilStrokePoint.html#bpy.types.GPencilStrokePoint). This data structure doesn't store group weights, though.
[GPencilStroke](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.GPencilStroke.html#bpy.types.GPencilStroke) does store group weights in `groups`, but this is only one set of weights per-stroke, not per-point (each stroke has many `points`).
Is there some other data structure I need to access for the weight data?

Comment: If you look here https://developer.blender.org/file/view/9604908/source/$1172 around 1173 it appears that it is not exposed to python API. Write a patch?  Can see that, as noted in question, how the stroke is.https://developer.blender.org/file/view/9604908/source/$1584